# Winding number vs turning number for an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, contour-integration

The definitions of winding number and turning number can be seen in [this other stack overflow question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031635/turning-number-vs-winding-number).

I am reading a physics paper that claims (i.e uses it as an argument) that (A) the winding number of a contour $C$ (which is a path on the complex domain) on the function f(z) is **exactly** half the number of times the function becomes real along the contour.

EDIT: to be clear, it follows from the [argument principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle) that f(z) is real **atleast** twice the winding number. But my problem stems from this being an **exact** equality.

To my mind, this **can** to be true, if  (B) arg(f(z)) along the image of the contour $C$ has to be a monotonic function of arg(z). I *think* that it is **necessary** to demand that (C) the winding and turning number are the same along the image of the contour $C$ for $f(z)$.

Is there a condition that f can abide by that would lead to the initial argument A being true? Or any of the weaker conditions (B and C) that I mention after that?

PS the physics paper in question is V Heine 1963 Proc. Phys. Soc. 81 300, specifically equations 12 and 13.

Answer (score 0):

If the contour only cuts the $x$-axis transversally, then the winding
number is $\sum\epsilon_j$ where $\epsilon_i=1$ or $-1$ according to
whether at the $j$-th intersection the curve crosses the
**positive** $x$-axis anti-clockwise or clockwise.
(for simplicity I will assume the contour starts and ends off the $x$-axis). So if the argument is always increasing, all the $\epsilon_j=1$.
There is a corresponding formula on the negative $x$-axis.
So if the argument is increasing he formula of Heine is valid. Otherwise
one needs to take into account the intersections when the contour
crosses the axis in the "wrong" direction. Again this can only work
if all the intersections are transverse.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is presumes  condition (B). I asked if there is a class of  complex functions that has this property that arg(f(z) ) monotonically increases or decreases along a contour (encompassing a convex region? ).